# amazon.aws.ec2_instance throwing "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a simple task to terminate an EC2 instance:

```yaml
- name: ec2_instance module - Terminate EC2 Instance
  amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
    region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
    name: "{{ ec2_name }}"
    state: terminated
  register: ec2
```

This throws an error:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689314444.0447388-8-263549951178931/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance.py\", line 107, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689314444.0447388-8-263549951178931/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689314444.0447388-8-263549951178931/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.modules.ec2_instance', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.modules.ec2_instance', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File \"\", line 226, in run_module\n  File \"\", line 98, in _run_module_code\n  File \"\", line 88, in _run_code\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload_mp9fer50/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_instance.py\", line 2203, in \n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload_mp9fer50/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_instance.py\", line 2172, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload_mp9fer50/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_instance.py\", line 2037, in build_filters\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload_mp9fer50/ansible_amazon.aws.ec2_instance_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_instance.py\", line 1573, in get_default_subnet\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

Can anyone tell me why it's throwing this error and how to resolve it?